# boost log every hour

Tags: file, logging, boost, rotation

I'm using boost log and I want to make basic log principal file: new error log at the beginning of each hour (if error exists), and to name it like "file_%Y%m%d%H.log". 
I have 2 problems with this boost library:
1. How to rotate file at the beginning of each hour?
This isn't possible with rotation_at_time_interval parameter because it creates new file regarding first written record in file, and the hour in file name doesn't match that rule. Is it possible to have multiple rotation_at_time_point for one file in sink or is there some other solution?
2. When file exceed some size I want it to start new file and in that case it should append some index to file name. With adding rotation_size parametar and %N to file name it will increment N all the time while application is running. I want that N to be reset at the beginning of each hour, just as my file name changes. Does anybody have any idea how to do that with this boost log library?

This is basic principal in creating log files in industry. I really don't understand how this can't be done with library which is dedicated for creating log files.

Answer (score 0):

Library itself doesn't provide a way to rotate file at the begging of every hour, but i had same problem so i used a function wrapper, which return true on begging of every hour. 
I find this way better for me, because i can controll efficency of code.

from boost.org:

```
bool is_it_time_to_rotate();


void init_logging(){

boost::shared_ptr< sinks::text_file_backend > backend =
    boost::make_shared< sinks::text_file_backend >(
        keywords::file_name = "file_%5N.log",
        keywords::time_based_rotation = &is_it_time_to_rotate
    );
```

}

For a second question i really dont undrestand it well.